# What happens when parachain is waiting for slot?

Tags: polkadot, parachain, relay-chain

Is there a way to produce and finalize blocks when a parachain is waiting for a slot on polkadot. Lets consider a scenario where there is a parachain who has applied for the slot on polkadot but did not get any slot for 2years so what happens in those 2years is it just waiting to be added as a parachain or is it producing and finalizing blocks with its own consensus?

Answer (score 1):

A few scenarios I see:

- You wait for the next auction and win the next slot; in the meantime you will not produce and finalize any blocks

  - probably not what you wanted but a the end of the day that is what you're bidding for: high quality blockspace for a period of time
- You could become a parathread and subscribe to the pay-as-you-go model until you have an opportunity to win the next slot

  - parathreads are on the roadmap, you can learn more [here](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-parathreads).
- You run a Substrate solo chain and when you win the next slot, you migrate your solo chain to your parachain

  - downside here is the quality of the blockspace
- You could run a smart contract to finalize your transactions on a parachain that already has a secured slot while you wait for the next slot